# Hard Drive not working with VirtualBox on Mac OS X 10.10.2

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, virtualbox

Basically,

I have a Seagate Expansion Drive (1TB), I have ejected it from my MacBook and mounted it into the guest virtual machine, it comes up with the message:

> This USB device can perform faster if you connect it to a Hi-Speed USB 2.0 port.

as if it were recognized, and then when I go to Devices and Printers, the Hard Drive is in the "Unspecified" section, and has a warning sign next to it, I click on it and then it says it needs troubleshooting, I go through the troubleshooting process, and it says that I need to re-install the device driver, so I click "apply", and it searches for a driver, and then it shows that it's installing the device driver software and it comes up with:

> Device driver software was not successfully installed

It says the hard drive has a driver problem, when I have been using it fine on OS X?

Comment: What format, what guest OS? Those look like Windows messages - so if the drive is HFS+ Windows won't be able to read it without 3rd party support.

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit Guest OS and the drive format is FAT

Comment: Could you edit your question to include that data - then the next thing I'd try is the drive back on the Mac first, then Windows after a VM reboot, rather than suspend.

Comment: I've tried re-installing the VM and it still doesn't work. So I might just go for the Windows 10 Technical Preview

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not natively support USB 3.0, which is what the [Seagate® Expansion Desktop 1TB USB Drive - Specs](http://www.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/desktop-hard-drives/expansion-hard-drive/#specs) interface is.  To work around this Windows 7 native limitation, if no USB 3.0 3rd party driver for this device is available, you should be able to get it work by either plugging it into a USB 2.0 Port or into a USB 2.0 Hub before attaching it to the virtual machine.

Comment: I have a USB hub connecting from my MacBook

Comment: Is it a USB 2.0 or 3.0 Hub?

Comment: It doesn't say - it just says for PC and Mac, compatible with Windows 2000, Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7,

Comment: Is it an old Hub? Base on the message you posted it might be a USB 1.x Hub and that might be an issue.  What does it show in System Information under USB for that Hub, when connected to OS X not the VM, or from a Terminal: `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`

Comment: >
            USB2.0 Hub:

              Product ID: 0x0608
              Vendor ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
              Version: 77.64
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
              Location ID: 0xfd120000 / 4
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100

Comment: Well that should have worked as the USB 2.0 Hub workaround is the standard workaround for Windows 7 not natively supporting USB 3.0.

Comment: I'm going to try and install Windows 10 Technical Preview and put that on instead